# How to classify multi-class data at different probability cutoff in Weka

Tags: class, weka, random-forest, multiclass-classification, machine-learning-model

Weka set default cutoff (i.e. 50%) to discriminate its data of two class and can easily classify on different cutoff by using *SelectThreshold classifier* in Weka interface. Now in a three class data, Weka choose the highest probability, say from probability of 0.333, 0.421, 0.246, Weka will select 0.421. But in this class it is not possible to select a custom cutoff manually. Is there any method by which i can perform this task or some one can help me understanding the concept custom cutoff in multi-class data.

example of two class data

```
inst#,    actual, predicted, error, probability distribution
 1       1:+1       1:+1         *0.814  0.186
 2       1:+1       1:+1         *1      0    
 3       1:+1       1:+1         *0.58   0.42 
 4       1:+1       2:-1      +   0.294 *0.706
 5       1:+1       1:+1         *0.796  0.204
 6       1:+1       1:+1         *0.989  0.011
 7       1:+1       2:-1      +   0.294 *0.706
 8       1:+1       1:+1         *0.814  0.186
```

example of three class data

```
inst#,    actual, predicted, error, probability distribution
 1       1:+1       1:+1         *0.92   0.07   0.01 
 2       1:+1       1:+1         *0.97   0.03   0    
 3       1:+1        2:0      +   0.47  *0.52   0.01 
 4       1:+1       1:+1         *0.89   0.08   0.03 
 5       1:+1       1:+1         *0.643  0.338  0.02 
 6       1:+1        2:0      +   0.22  *0.73   0.05 
 7       1:+1       1:+1         *0.45   0.21   0.34 
 8       1:+1       3:-1      +   0.16   0.19  *0.65
```